# I have a VBA Query

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a `VBA` code to find the last row in an excel sheet and delete the rows above till we reach the headers on `row1`.
I am continuously getting a compile error with end`(XLUP)`
Here is my code:

```
Dim rw As Integer
Range("A1048576").End(xlup).Select
rw = ActiveCell.Row
Cells.Select
Range("A" & rw).Activate
Selection.DELETE Shift:=xlup
Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: Is this code in a loop? Because it seems to me you are deleting only one cell and not rows as you say...

Comment: start with `Dim rw As Long`

Comment: @jivko - it deletes all the cells in the worksheet.

Comment: *'getting a compile error'* is **not** a valid error code nor an adequate error description.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `rw As Long`

You may try this to clear the cells in column A except the header row1.

```
Dim rw As Long
rw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
If rw > 1 Then Range("A2:A" & rw).Clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
with worksheets("sheet1")
    .cells(1, 1).currentregion.offset(1, 0).clear
end with
```

Comment: You should have wrapped this code within `With` and `End With` block as I am not sure OP can implement this solution. The another point is, the proposed code will clear the current region not only the column A which seems to be the intention of the code provided by OP.

Answer (score 0):

If your column A values are contiguous (i.e. doesn't have blanks in between) then Jeeped solution is the way to go

otherwise you may want to use:

```
With Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) 'reference last not empty cell in column A
    If .Row > 1 Then .Offset(-.Row + 2).Resize(.Row - 1).EntireRow.Delete xlUp
End With
```

in both cases, you can choose between following methods to act on wanted range:

- .ClearContents (to clear the range content only, preserving formatting and notes)
- .Clear (to clear the whole content of the range, formats and notes included)
- .Delete (to remove the range, it has the same effect of .Clear plus rows shifting)

the methods above are listed from the less *invasive* (mainly, time consuming) to the most one